# Select row with highest number of referring rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project where every time a video is viewed, a row is added into the `views` table with the video ID and the viewers IP.

I was wondering how I would select the video from the `videos` table with the largest amount of rows referring to it in the `views` table.

Example:

```
VIEWS
Video: 1234 IP: 123.234.456
Video: 1234 IP: 768.346.467
Video: 4321 IP: 123.234.456

VIDEOS
Video: 1234 By: user123
Video: 4321 By: randomuser456
```

In this situation, I would like the row with video `1234` selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT videos.video, COUNT(views.ip) as views
FROM videos
JOIN views ON videos.video = views.video
GROUP BY video.video
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 1
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06b48/4

Comment: Shouldnt it be `ORDER BY views DESC`?

Comment: @simshaun: Whoops.  Yes, it should.  Thanks.

Comment: @simshaun: I'm running out of Mt. Dew, guess I clicked on the wrong name when it was auto-completing.